# gas behavior in VBA

Tags: vba

my project is to predict non-ideal gas movement, so i wrote this code to give every molecule a specific number, but it keeps repeating numbers (i used randbetween)
how do i chnge it so it wont repeat the same number?

Sub Rand_Number()
'áåçø 20 àçåæ ùì îñôøé äîåì÷åìåú

```
Dim RandNum As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim Mone As Integer

Mone = 0
Num_molecules = Sheets("Data").Range("A14").Value
RandNum = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, Num_molecules)

For j = 1 To Num_molecules * 0.2

    If IsEmpty(Sheets("rand").Cells(1, 1)) = True Then
           Sheets("rand").Cells(1, 1) = RandNum

    Else

    i = 1
    'RandNum = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, Num_molecules)
          Do 'Until IsEmpty(Sheets("rand").Cells(i, 1)) = True

          If Sheets("rand").Cells(i, 1) = RandNum Then
          RandNum = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, Num_molecules)

          Do Until RandNum = Cells(i, 1) Or IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) = True
               If RandNum = Sheets("rand").Cells(i, 1) Then
                    RandNum = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, Num_molecules)
               Else
                 i = i + 1

              End If
          Loop


            ElseIf IsEmpty(Sheets("rand").Cells(i, 1)) = False Then
            i = i + 1

            Else
             Sheets("rand").Cells(i, 1) = RandNum

             Exit Do

            End If

      Loop
    End If


Next j
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a dictionary to keep track of the random numbers that have been generated so far. If the number doesn't exist in the dictionary you can proceed with the simulation, otherwise you could generate a new random number (this would be the Else condition)

Using a dictionary is very fast for doing the lookup.

Here's a code sample of how to work with a dictionary.

```
Public Sub DictionaryExample()
    Dim myDict          As Object: Set myDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim myRand          As Long
    Dim i               As Long
    
    For i = 1 To 10000
        myRand = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)
        If myDict.exists(myRand) = False Then ' The random number doesn't exist in the previous items added
                                              'If it doesn't exist, add it to the dictionary
            myDict.Add myRand, myRand 'First parameter is the key, or the unique value
                                      'The second parameter is the value associated with the key, the lookup value
        Else
            'Do something here when it does exist
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Ryan - this implementation is faster because it doesn't generate all unique numbers from the range, but only a portion of it. I've updated my answer to this question which uses both your approach to weed out dups as well as doing so until all numbers from the range have been generated. It is still faster than using `Remove`. I've linked to GitHub Gist with all three to compare performance. Results are at the bottom of the source file. Have a look! :-)

Comment: @LoganReed. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem, but enumerating all random numbers in a range say from 1-10,000 isn't what the OP is after. I think what's needed is just don't repeat a random number based on N number of simulations. If we don't want repeats, why not just do a For i = 1 to 10000 loop, or something similar?

Comment: You are right - I am probably overthinking it. OP needs to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Generation of numbers until all numbers from the range are generated. It is inefficient as towards the end of the algorithm most random numbers become a "miss", but it is still more efficient than collection's remove method below.

```
Sub uniqRndMissedHits()

    Dim lb As Long: lb = 1    ' lower bound
    Dim ub As Long: ub = 1000 ' upper bound

    ' populate collection with numbers starting from lb to ub
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As New Collection

    ' iterate while we haven't generated all the random numbers
    ' in the specified range
    While c.Count < ub - lb + 1
        i = Int((ub - lb + 1) * Rnd + lb)
        If Not contains(c, CStr(i)) Then
            c.Add i, CStr(i)
            Debug.Print i ' this is your unique random number from the
                          ' remaining in the collection
        End If
    Wend

End Sub

Function contains(col As Collection, key As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    col.Item key
    contains = (Err.Number = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

This example generates a guaranteed unique (i.e. previously not generated) values, but `Remove` method of the `Collection` makes it inefficient for large number of simulations.

```
Sub uniqRnd()

    Dim lb As Long: lb = 1    ' lower bound
    Dim ub As Long: ub = 1000 ' upper bound

    ' populate collection with numbers starting from lb to ub
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As New Collection
    For i = lb To ub: c.Add i: Next

    ' randomly pick the number and (!) remove it from the
    ' collection at the same time so it won't be repeated
    While c.Count > 0
        lb = 1
        ub = c.Count
        i = Int((ub - lb + 1) * Rnd + lb)
        Debug.Print c(i) ' this is your unique random number from the
                         ' remaining in the collection
        c.Remove i
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comparison of performance of all the methods in this answer can be found in this GitHub Gist [Excel VBA: Generate complete set of unique random numbers](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3dc248114b6c5d06bcb51202dc54774b)

Comment: Interesting method, I like the idea! I profiled your code where ub = 100000, as I suspected a large number of iterations might be slow. It took about 20 seconds to execute. Using the dictionary method I posted completed in just under 2 seconds. I suspect it has something to do with the remove method of the collection data structure. I bet the method you posted would be considerably faster if you used a dictionary data structure.

Comment: @RyanWildry Ha - very unexpected. Looks like `Remove` method of the `Collection` is very inefficient (probably copying an entire collection over an over). I thought that on large number of values your method will perform much worse -- because there will be too many misses. But it looks like lots of random misses is still way "cheaper" than `Collection.Remove`. Let me think about it...